# How to programatically communicate with a debugger like GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb, vim

I'm trying to write some vimscript that will communicate with dubuggers, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing it. Is there a way I can send input to a debugger and read its output programatically?

I know this is possible because Code::Blocks, Eclipse, and other IDEs do this somehow. I'm just wondering how it can be done.

Comment: Stop wondering and start reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm just wondering how it can be done.

GDB has "machine interface" just for that. Details [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html).

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.18 shows an interesting way to wrap and communicate with a debugger, gdb or others.

See [commit 8424364](https://github.com/git/git/commit/842436466aa5d9f1e5f1a09d41d22d902006219c) (24 Apr 2018) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 89753dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89753dc2b72d838c0bae22ef708201b6473a1244), 23 May 2018)</sup>

> ### Make running `git` under other debugger-like programs easy
>
> This allows us to run `git`, when using the script from `bin-wrappers`, under
>   other programs.
>   A few examples for usage within testsuite scripts:
>
> ```
> debug git checkout master
> debug --debugger=nemiver git $ARGS
> debug -d "valgrind --tool-memcheck --track-origins=yes" git $ARGS
> ```
>
> Or, if someone has `bin-wrappers/` in their `$PATH` and is executing `git` outside the testsuite:
>
> ```
> GIT_DEBUGGER="gdb --args" git $ARGS
> GIT_DEBUGGER=nemiver git $ARGS
> GIT_DEBUGGER="valgrind --tool=memcheck --track-origins=yes" git $ARGS
> ```
>
> There is also a handy shortcut of `GIT_DEBUGGER=1` meaning the same as
>
> ```
> GIT_DEBUGGER="gdb --args"
> ```

See the result in [`t/test-lib-functions.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/842436466aa5d9f1e5f1a09d41d22d902006219c/t/test-lib-functions.sh#L148-L170).

---

About that `GIT_DEBUGGER`, Git 2.23 documents it.

See [commit f547101](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f547101b26449c65aefd378022277ebb953eb7a6) (28 May 2019) by [Emily Shaffer (`nasamuffin`)](https://github.com/nasamuffin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7df94cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7df94cd1f691dd6ccb3038e1b77544030aab3fed), 17 Jun 2019)</sup>

> ### `doc`: hint about `GIT_DEBUGGER` in `CodingGuidelines`
>
> We check for a handy environment variable `GIT_DEBUGGER` when running via
>   `bin-wrappers/`, but this feature is undocumented.
>
> Add a hint to how to use it into the `CodingGuidelines` (which is where other useful environment settings like `DEVELOPER` are documented).

So [`Documentation/CodingGuidelines`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f547101b26449c65aefd378022277ebb953eb7a6/Documentation/CodingGuidelines#L415-L419) now includes:

> You can launch `gdb` around your program using the shorthand `GIT_DEBUGGER`.
>
> - Run `GIT_DEBUGGER=1 ./bin-wrappers/git foo` to simply use `gdb` as is, or
> - run `GIT_DEBUGGER="<debugger> <debugger-args>" ./bin-wrappers/git foo` to
>     use your own debugger and arguments.
>     Example: `GIT_DEBUGGER="ddd --gdb" ./bin-wrappers/git log` (See `wrap-for-bin.sh`.)